# Power Platform integration with Azure APIM previsioned in a VNet internal mode

Tags: azure-api-management, powerapps, power-platform

We have an Azure APIM provision in a VNet internal mode as described in this article: [Connect to an internal virtual network using Azure API Management | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-internal-vnet?tabs=stv2). We can successfully consume APIs in APIM with Postman and via the Developer Portal, from within the corporate network. However, we don’t have any connectivity between Power Platform and APIM; error message while testing a Custom Connector from Power Apps:

[image]

Can someone please point me in the right direction on how to enable comms between Power Platform and Azure APIM in VNet Internal mode. Any links and reference material are highly appreciated.

Comment: Please have a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/vnet/create-data-gateways

Comment: @MarkusMeyer thanks will do and relate back with an update

Comment: Hi @MarkusMeyer, we did look into VNet Data Gateway but decided not to proceed with it at the feature is still in preview. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We decide on provisioning of Applcation Gateway with WAF applied in front of APIM that only allows traffic in from Power Platform. Reference blog post here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/apim-with-application-gateway-v1/ba-p/1795180.

Comment: Can you please share the interest of an application gateway in this case? Between what the traffic is redirected as you only have APIM? Thanks